# flutter doctor --android-licenses Error, how to fix this?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

Error: Could not find or load main class M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\

[image: 1]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

On macbook big sur with m1 chip this work for me:

- Run android studio.
- Select configure and click on sdk manager.
- Find the "SDK tools" option on android sdk menu.
- select and install android SDK commant tools (or "Android SDK (obsolete) founded in other tutorial)"
- try run flutter doctor ... again

I hope this work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed Android Studio yet, so install Android Studio, and create a new Android emulator. If not,
your Java SDK version might be the problem.
Download JAVA SE 8 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html).

- Uninstall any previously installed JDKs and install this anew.
- Copy path of `\bin` of the JDK.
- Open Environment Variables in your PC.
- Add a new variable `JAVA_HOME` with the copied value.

[image: JAVA_HOME]

- Now retry `flutter doctor`.